# Is it possible to use non-imported packages in a package vignette?

Tags: r

I'm writing a vignette for one of my packages.

In this vignette, I would like to demonstrate how this package can interact with other packages that are **not** being imported by the `NAMESPACE` or by the `Imports` section of the `DESCRIPTION` file.

So, I'm putting a `require` call to use these external packages in my vignette, but of course I got the following `NOTE` when I try to `R CMD check` the package:

```
* checking for unstated dependencies in vignettes ... NOTE
‘library’ or ‘require’ call not declared from: ‘RColorBrewer’
```

Is there any way around this, or should I either import these external packages or "fake" the vignette using `eval=FALSE`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Put it in `Suggests:` of your `DESCRIPTION` file.

From p. 6 of the [R extensions manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html):

> The ‘Suggests’ field uses the same syntax as ‘Depends’ and lists
>   packages that are not necessarily needed. This includes packages used
>   only in examples, tests or vignettes (see Section 1.4 [Writing package
>   vignettes], page 26), and packages loaded in the body of functions.
>   E.g., suppose an example from package `foo` uses a dataset from package
>   `bar`. Then it is not necessary to have `bar` use `foo` unless one wants to
>   execute all the examples/tests/vignettes: it is useful to have `bar`,
>   but not necessary. Version requirements can be specified, and will be
>   used by `R CMD check`.

Comment: Thanks Ben, that did the trick - I just did not understand the capabilities behind the `Suggests` field obviously. Sorry it turns out to be a bit of a RTFM question!

Answer (score 8):

In addition if the vignette properly depends on that package, there should be a

```
% \VignetteDepends{...}
```

statement in the vignette itself: [Sweave, Part II: Package Vignettes, R News 3/2 (Oct. 2003), 21 - 24.](http://www.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2003-2.pdf)

However, your case possibly is a bit different:

I use `if (require ("pkgxy"))` without `% \\VignetteDepends{pkgxy}` (`Suggests: pkgxy` in the DESCRIPTION is needed anyways) for some things I want to show but where I don't want to force the user to have all the suggested pacakges installed. I put a box at the beginning of the vignette where I report which of those packages are available and if a package is not available when the vignette is built, an "pkgxy is needed to do this" text is put into the vignette.

The ["introduction" vignette of package hyperSpec](http://hyperspec.r-forge.r-project.org/blob/introduction.pdf) is an example (to find out how it actually works, you need not only [the .Rnw](http://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/%2acheckout%2a/pkg/hyperSpec/vignettes/introduction.Rnw?root=hyperspec) but also [some more definitions](http://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/%2acheckout%2a/pkg/hyperSpec/vignettes/vignettes.defs?root=hyperspec)).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! The link to hyperSpec "introduction" is down, perhaps best start [here](http://hyperspec.r-forge.r-project.org/)  instead.