# Rmd Vignette fails in devtools::check because of missing package

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

I'm developing an R package. The vignette is an .Rmd that loads `ggplot` using `library(ggplot2)`. I'm trying to get it to pass checks. The checks are failing to build the Vignette because it says that that `ggplot2` is missing. Following Hadley's advice [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/vignettes.html#vignette-cran) and other advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899943/is-it-possible-to-use-non-imported-packages-in-a-package-vignette), I've done the following to try to get the check to install the packages that are only dependencies for the vignette:

- Added the packages to the the `Suggests:` field in the DESCRIPTION file
- Added the packages to the top of the vignette `%\VignetteDepends{ggplot2}` in the same block where the other commands go. So for example the header for the Vignette reads:

---

```
---
title: "VIGNETTE"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  rmarkdown::html_vignette:
    default
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{VIGNETTE}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
  %\VignetteDepends{ggplot2}
---
```

The vignette works fine when I install ggplot2. However, it doesn't know to install the dependencies without manually installing it. This leads to both `devtools::build_vignettes()` and `devtools::check()` failing with the following error:

```
Error: processing vignette 'VIGNETTE.Rmd' failed with diagnostics:
there is no package called 'ggplot2'
```

Any advice? Thank you.

Comment: If you want to build the vignette, you'll need to install ggplot2. Is something unclear?

Comment: I'm building the package. Shouldn't all the suggested packages install when running `devtools::check()`?

Comment: Ok, so there is no way to have a dependency in your vignette that is not an overall dependency and still pass checks. For example, see here: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/vignettes.html#vignette-cran