# Using packages that are not imported as part of examples in a vignette

Tags: r, devtools

I am using functions from the `forcats` and `devtools` packages in a vignette for a package I am developing. I have them listed in the `Suggests` (not not `Imports`) field in the NAMESPACE file.

When I run `devtools::check()`, the following NOTE is returned:

```
checking for unstated dependencies in vignettes ... NOTE
'::' or ':::' imports not declared from:
  ‘devtools’ ‘forcats’
```

According to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899943/is-it-possible-to-use-non-imported-packages-in-a-package-vignette) on Stack Overflow, adding these to the Suggests field ought to resolve the issue causing the note, but this doesn't seem to do so for me in this case. Can you recommend how you would address this note? If it is helpful, a link to the package is [here](https://github.com/jrosen48/konfound).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Suggests* need to be added to your **DESCRIPTION** file, not **NAMESPACE**

#### Example from `dplyr`

```
Type: Package
Package: dplyr
Version: 0.7.4
Title: A Grammar of Data Manipulation
Description: A fast, consistent tool for working with data frame like objects,
    both in memory and out of memory.
Authors@R: c(
    person("Hadley", "Wickham", , "hadley@rstudio.com", c("aut", "cre")),
    person("Romain", "Francois", , "romain@r-enthusiasts.com", role = "aut"),
    person("Lionel", "Henry", role = "aut"),
    person("Kirill", "Müller", role = "aut"),
    person("RStudio", role = c("cph", "fnd"))
    )
URL: http://dplyr.tidyverse.org, https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr
BugReports: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues
Encoding: UTF-8
Depends: R (>= 3.1.2)
Imports: assertthat, bindrcpp (>= 0.2), glue (>= 1.1.1), magrittr,
        methods, pkgconfig, rlang (>= 0.1.2), R6, Rcpp (>= 0.12.7),
        tibble (>= 1.3.1), utils
Suggests: bit64, covr, dbplyr, dtplyr, DBI, ggplot2, hms, knitr, Lahman
        (>= 3.0-1), mgcv, microbenchmark, nycflights13, rmarkdown,
        RMySQL, RPostgreSQL, RSQLite, testthat, withr
VignetteBuilder: knitr
LinkingTo: Rcpp (>= 0.12.0), BH (>= 1.58.0-1), bindrcpp, plogr
LazyData: yes
License: MIT + file LICENSE
RoxygenNote: 6.0.1
NeedsCompilation: yes
Packaged: 2017-09-16 15:25:52 UTC; muelleki
Author: Hadley Wickham [aut, cre],
  Romain Francois [aut],
  Lionel Henry [aut],
  Kirill Müller [aut],
  RStudio [cph, fnd]
Maintainer: Hadley Wickham <hadley@rstudio.com>
Repository: CRAN
Date/Publication: 2017-09-28 20:43:29 UTC
Built: R 3.4.2; x86_64-w64-mingw32; 2017-09-29 11:50:50 UTC; windows
Archs: i386, x64
```

#### Update

After looking at your link, I see you have a typo in your file, correctly move the items from *Suggets* to *Suggests*

```
Suggets: forcats,
    devtools
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 6.0.1
Suggests: knitr,
    rmarkdown
```